# Создание списка кортежей из двух списков Python

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется 2 списка `[1,2,4,5,6,8,13]` и `[3,7,9,10,11,12,14]`. Из них нужно сделать вот такой список кортежей: `[(1,2,3),(4,5,7),(6,8,9),(13,14)]`. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Поясните в вопросе, какое правило формирования элементов?

Comment: 2 числа из первого и 1 число из второго ?

Comment: @Интик Это понятно, но непонятно с хвостом

Answer (score 3):

```py
a = [1,2,4,5,6,8,13]
b = [3,7,9,10,11,12,14]

result = [(1,2,3),(4,5,7),(6,8,9),(13,14)]
```

Comment: Смешно, но пользы не несёт )

Comment: Почему же - отличный ответ, соответствует уровню детализации проблемы )

Answer (score 1):

Я воспроизвёл, но всё же поясните принцип, с последними элементами непонятно %)

```
a = [1,2,4,5,6,8,13]
b = [3,7,9,10,11,12,14]

c = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(a[::2],a[1::2],b)]
c.append((a[-1],b[-1]))

print(c)
```

Вывод:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 7), (6, 8, 9), (13, 14)]
```